# Using environment variables for Gradle builds in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, environment-variables

We decided to use GitHub as our version control. I know the [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) build scripts use certain paths, such as the Android SDK path in the `local.properties` file.

Since this path will differ between the five of us, I think the projects will fail to build on my teammates' machines when they pull changes from GitHub. Is this correct?

If so, can we all make an environment variable called something like `ANDROID_SDK` and use that for the `sdk.dir` in the `local.properties`?  Would the project properly build on all of our machines if we used the environment variable? Are there any other places where we may need to set 
a similar environment variable? Will this work? If so, how do we do this?

I am not sure if this is the best way to go about setting up a team project for Android. I'm looking for suggestions on a best practice for this.

Comment: Projects should build fine regardless of where the SDK is installed on the developer's machine.  local.properties is a generated file and should not be checked into source control (as the comments in that file indicate).  Maybe you could be specific about the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson.  I think there may have been some user error by one of my teammates as he said Android Studio Couldn't find his SDK path.  Everything was working fine for me, I was just wondering if I had to do anything special to ensure the builds would work when other people pulled it down.

Comment: For me, it's committed into my repository. I saw all of my repos, and all of them have `local.properties`, while in `.gitignore` they all have this line: `/local.properties`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this correct?

No, because IMHO `local.properties` should not be in your Git repo. The standard Android Studio `.gitignore` file (created when you create the project) has `local.properties`, meaning that `local.properties` would not be committed to your repo.

As Doug Stevenson points out in a comment, `local.properties` is generated when you import a project. It will be driven by Android Studio settings.

> can we all make an environment variable called something like ANDROID_SDK and use that for the sdk.dir in the local.properties?

Not for use with Android Studio, at least the last I tried it. For command-line Gradle builds, that works fine, but Android Studio does not pass the environment to its forked Gradle process.

Comment: Thanks for the information, sorry if that was a dumb question.  The reason I asked this was because a while back we set up a test app where I pushed it up to GitHub and few of the students had some issues.  One said Android Studio couldn't find his SDK directory, but maybe he had bigger issues not related to my test app. At that time we were only a few weeks into the course so there was probably some user error :)  It sounds like everyone should be able to build and edit the project app without me having to do anything special after committing.  Thanks again!

Comment: @crmackey: "sorry if that was a dumb question" -- no, because Android projects do not have the best system for identifying what is and is not something that should be checked it. It's better than it used to be, but you still have lingering things like `local.properties`. And the environment variables bit is just a screwy decision on Google's part.